# AngularJS: {{EXPRESSION}} displaying as {{expression}} instead of result

Tags: html, angularjs, web-applications

**Fixed**: Thanks to @Sajeetharan, it was discovered that amongst other things the function the expression was attempting to display, GenerateRef, was broken and causing the issue.

---

I understand this is a reasonably common question but so far my following of other posts or tutorials has not been able to fix my issue with getting {{}} to display the result.

I am trying to make a simple web app to take in a new request. This is given a randomly generated ID which is then presented in a table and is what I'm having problems displaying in the table. Despite following tutorials and attempting to debug it I am unable to, probably as I am very new to Angular and HTML. Apologies in advance.

```js
angular.module('ReqWebApp', [])

pegasusWebApp.controller('ReqAppController', function ReqAppController($scope) {
    $scope.GenerateRef = ["RF" + date.now()]
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ReqWebApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>New Request</title>
    <script src="../../app.js"></script>
    <script src="../../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="ReqAppController">
    <p><span>Add New Request | Accept <input type="checkbox" name="accept"> | Decline <input type="checkbox" name="decline"></span></p>
    <table border="1">
        <tr><th>REF : {{GenerateRef}}</th> <th>Producer Reference : <input type="text" name="prodRef"></th></tr>
        <tr><th>Producer :
            <select>
                <option>EXAMPLE</option>
                <option>EXAMPLE</option>
            </select></th> <th>Producer Site : <input type="text"></th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

The script locations *should* be working locally for me (I have tested this) as I am using Bower and Node to install, maintain and run AngularJS and the project. I have tried setting out the AJS controller several different ways so far according to different tutorials and Stack Overflow posts and this is the current rendition as it was the most up to date I could find.

Also worth noting is there have been some edits to the snippet from the code I'm running and some typos or other errors may be a result of me changing variable names to post here.

Thanks to anyone taking the time to read through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have it as,

```
var pegasusWebApp = angular.module('ReqWebApp', [])

pegasusWebApp.controller('ReqAppController', function ReqAppController($scope) {
    $scope.GenerateRef = ["RF" + date.now()]
});
```

you are missing the declaration part. also angular reference should be loaded before loading app.js

```
 <script src="../../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
 <script src="../../app.js"></script>
```

**DEMO**

```js
var pegasusWebApp = angular.module('ReqWebApp', [])

pegasusWebApp.controller('ReqAppController', function ReqAppController($scope) {
    $scope.GenerateRef = ["RF" + new Date()]
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ReqWebApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>New Request</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 
</head>

<body ng-controller="ReqAppController">
    <p><span>Add New Request | Accept <input type="checkbox" name="accept"> | Decline <input type="checkbox" name="decline"></span></p>
    <table border="1">
        <tr><th>REF : {{GenerateRef}}</th> <th>Producer Reference : <input type="text" name="prodRef"></th></tr>
        <tr><th>Producer :
            <select>
                <option>EXAMPLE</option>
                <option>EXAMPLE</option>
            </select></th> <th>Producer Site : <input type="text"></th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I have made the above edits, however, and it's still showing as {{reqAppController.GenerateRef}}.

Comment: Sorry. New to stack overflow and attempted to start a new line with enter and posted early. Now edited. Is there anything else blaring that may be causing it? Maybe I should forgo bower's AJS and attempt to force an override to the latest version?

Comment: @ConnorBarthelmie check the demo

Comment: Thank you very much! Your "new Date()" addition fixed it :) Will mark as answered.